# how to save the data entered in text boxes in PHP CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-plugins, session-variables

in PHP  CodeIgniter application there are several pages with input text boxes and text areaas.

How to implement the session save in php i.e. whnever the user closes the tab,

the entered data should remain saved until the user logs out of the application.
or is there any plugin available to achieve the same ?

Sample HTML - (view page in ci)

```
<div class="row">
    <!--  <div class="panel-heading" value="" readonly="readonly">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" value="New Entry for All fields" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;">
</div> -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Name of fielded persons
        <input type="text" name="fieldEE[]" class="form-control  fieldEE" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Alias
        <input type="text" name="ALIASNAME[]" class="form-control ALIASNAME" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Sex
        <select class="form-control" name="SEX[]">
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="F">Female</option>
            <option value="O">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Age
        <input type="number" name="AGE[]" class="form-control" value="" required="required" min="1" max="99" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Address
        <textarea style="width: 100%" name="ADDRESS[]" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Father/Husband Name
        <input type="text" name="FATHER_HUSBAND[]" class="form-control" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Religion
        <select class="form-control" name="RELIGION[]">
            <option value="M">Hinduism</option>
            <option value="F">Islam</option>
            <option value="F">Cristianity</option>
            <option value="F">Sikhism</option>
            <option value="F">Unkown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Occupation
        <select class="form-control" name="PROFESSION[]">
            <option selected="" value="GOVT. SERVICE">GOVT. SERVICE</option>
            <option value="MEDIA PERSON">MEDIA PERSON</option>
            <option value="BUSINESSMAN">BUSINESSMAN</option>
            <option value="ACADEMICIAN">ACADEMICIAN</option>
            <option value="DOCTOR">DOCTOR</option>
            <option value="HAWKER">HAWKER</option>
            <option value="DRIVER">DRIVER</option>
            <option value="FOOTHPATH DWELLER">FOOTHPATH DWELLER</option>
            <option value="PROSTITUTION">PROSTITUTION</option>
            <option value="MAOIST">MAOIST</option>
            <option value="LAWYER">LAWYER</option>
            <option value="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        fielded Date
        <div class='input-group date datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="field_DATE[]" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">         </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        fielded Half
        <select class="form-control" name="HALF[]">
            <option value="M">1st</option>
            <option value="F">2nd</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Against
        <select name="fieldAGAINST[]" id="fieldAGAINST" class="form-control fieldAGAINST">
            <option value="FIR">Against FIR</option>
            <option value="WfieldANT">Against Wfieldant</option>
            <option selected="" value="PETTY">In Petty Case</option>
            <option value="SPECIFIC">Specific field</option>
            <option value="PART-II">Part-II Case</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        FIR Number
        <input type="text" name="CASENO[]" id="CASENO" class="form-control CASENO" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        FIR Date
        <div class='input-group date datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' name="CASE_YR[]" id="CASE_YR" class="form-control CASE_YR" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Place Of field
        <input type="text" name="PLACE_field[]" class="form-control" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Region Sub
        <input type="text" name="LOCAL_OUTSIDE[]" class="form-control" value="" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="crimehead">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="under_section">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align: right; cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="add-row"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="dlt-row"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, can u post your code

Comment: Post some code that  what are you trying to do. You question is not clear enough to write an answer.

Comment: Actually it is a web application with several pages I need to implement the session save i.e. whenever any logged in user is typing any data it should be saved in somwhere until he/ she logs out of the application.

Comment: Like the session save functionality of a application